# Why can't I compare text from a TextArea to a String?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, jbutton, jtextarea

So I am obviously missing something completely obvious here. I have a button and an actionlistener hooked up to it. When I click the button, I want run an if statement that takes the contents of a TextArea and compares it to a String. Like So:

```
String a = "hello";
JTextArea area = new JTextArea("type something");
JButton button = new JButton("Go");

button. [insert actionlistener crap]

    //here's the important part:
    if (area.getText() == "hello"){
        //this will not be executed
    }
```

It's really weird. I even went through the debugger and at that if statement, both of those items are "hello". But it skips over it! What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: a lot of you are saying "use .equals". Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `String.equals()`  to compare the two. Not ==.

That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

You should do `area.getText()`, this is a method, not a property.

Also you should compare them with `equals` not with `==`.

So

```
"hello".equals(area.getText())
```

is the way to go.

Comment: That first was a mistake as I was typing the q, i didnt do that in the actual code.

Comment: +1 for being the first respondent to mention BOTH bugs.

Comment: @IsaiahTaylor The == checks for identity, equals checks for equality of the two values. For more details, visit the link provided by Teeg as a comment under your question.

Answer (score 3):

You need compare `String` with help of method [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 2):

You compare strings in java with equals(), not ==.

Answer (score 1):

As others are pointing out `String.equals` is needed.

The reason for this is that, `==` will check whether both objects are in fact the same object i.e. have the same memory address.

Comment: Use trim() method to skip white space in the textarea    **if (area.getText().trim().equals("hello"))**